# PHP request timing

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing a program to generate a random number in php, return it to a webpage and plot it on a graph. I've been debugging it a little and have noticed that when I call the request function, the webpage goes through the rest of the caller function before using returning the data from PHP. I need to get the data from the request and return it to the caller, then move on forward with the data I received from the request.

Here's the part of the caller function that keeps track in the console:

```
function plotData(dataSet) {

    var x = xScale+20; // 20 = margin length
    var y = 260;    //origin of graph

    getRequest();
    console.log("x = "+x);
    context.beginPath();

    x=x+xScale; //Move along the xAxis 

    console.log("dataSet = "+dataSet[0]+", "+dataSet[1]); 
    ...
}
```

And here's my PHP request:

```
function getRequest()
{
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    { // IE 6 and older
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }   
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   
      console.log('onReady');
      if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
      {
        if (request.status === 200)
        {
          random = request.responseText;
          random = parseInt(random);
          random = random/100;
          random = random.toFixed(2);
          console.log("random = " +random);
          data[1] = random;
          console.log("data = "+data[0]+", "+data[1]);
        }
        else
        {
          alert ('There was a problem with the request');
        }
      }
    }       
    request.open("GET", "external.php", true);
    request.send();     
}
```

And finally the console log:

```
onReady
x = 31.21951219512195
dataSet = 10, 10
onReady (x3)
random = 10.25
data = 10, 10.25
```

As you can see, the program is calling the all the console.log functions from `plotData()` before calling the functions from `getRequest()`.

This is problematic because I need to get the information from `getRequest()` before I can continue with `plotData()`.

One possible solution I just thought of is to make a 3rd function that executes after `plotData()` which does what I need it to do, but I feel like I should be able to handle it with the functions that I have.

Can someone explain why it goes through the caller function before the request function? And how can I fix it to wait for the request function to finish before moving forward with the caller?

Comment: Your `getRequest` function contains asynchronous code. There are many questions and answers regarding this issue. You have to use either callback functions or promises to solve your problem.

Comment: As @Cristy mentioned, you will need to look into Promises. Not all browsers support natively support them, so you'll need to use a polyfill or library. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @Cristy Thank you for your answer. I looked into Promises and I can't quite get a grasp on them. Could you point me in the direction of a question/answer regarding callback functions for this problem?